# Python, detect id and name within loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to verify `id` with `name` in loop.

**Example :**

I have 1 to `n` loop where (`1 - n`) is describe `id` (`id 1`, `id 2`, `to id n`), and each loop there will a random name given let say `a` until `c` repeated randomly, therefore I want to detect, for example if id `1` has `a` name counted `10 times` then id `1` name is `a` and if id `1` name is not `a` counter will be reset. I already tried, it only work in only 1 id, the issue is if it is more than one id counter seem reseting randomly.

Comment: You can try using a dictionary as a hash map to keep track of the ids and counts that you've already seen. Python also has the Counter class which could help here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Please learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please post your tried code which may helpful to solve your problem easily..